# Hibernate Fetching with Multiselect in Criteria API not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Hibernate Criteria API to load the data from the DB, however when using multiselect and fetching the related entities with mapping @OneToOne, @ManyToOne & @ManyToMany, I am getting error.

Code to get the data

```java
    private Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Account getGatewayAccount(Long appId, String accountNumber) {

        Session session = getSession();

        CriteriaBuilder criteria = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Account> query = criteria.createQuery(Account.class);
        Root<Account> from = query.from(Account.class);

        from.fetch(Account_.APP, JoinType.INNER);

        query.multiselect(from.get(Account_.ID), from.get(Account_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER))
                .where(criteria.equal(from.get(Account_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER), accountNumber),
                        criteria.equal(from.get(Account_.APP).get(App_.ID), appId));

        try {
            return session.createQuery(query)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried using EntityGraph to lad the data like below

```java
private Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Account getGatewayAccount(Long appId, String accountNumber) {

        Session session = getSession();

        RootGraph<Account> entityGraph = session.createEntityGraph(Account.class);
        entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("app");

        CriteriaBuilder criteria = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Account> query = criteria.createQuery(Account.class);
        Root<Account> from = query.from(Account.class);

        query.multiselect(from.get(Account_.ID), from.get(Account_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER))
                .where(criteria.equal(from.get(Account_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER), accountNumber),
                        criteria.equal(from.get(Account_.APP).get(App_.ID), appId));

        try {
            return session.createQuery(query)
                    .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The exception that I am getting is

```java
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, 
but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

I am looking a way which can fetch the related objects with multiselect in select clause and get the data as POJO object, not like a Tuple.

Answer (score 0):

What you want seems to be a [constructor query](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#construct-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...-)

```
  query.select(criteria.construct(Answer.class, from.get(Account_.ID), from.get(Account_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER))
```

This works by using a constructor on the defined class that accepts the two parameters define in the query, so bypasses all JPA hooks; What is returned is an unmanaged POJO. Since this isn't a managed entity fetch graphs will likely not have any meaning.

Otherwise, you can just return:

```
  query.select(from)
```

This will return an Address instance that is managed and has all attributes described in your entityGraph loaded. Depending on your provider specifics, everything not defined in the entityGraph should be left as lazy and so unfetched.

Comment: What you explained is quite basic and is know, I'm trying to understand, how do we fetch the related entities while doing a multiselect in the same query. If it cannot be done by Entity Graph, then maybe using fetch API of the Hibernate, like I tried in the first example

Comment: Also, using query.select(from) is not a right idea as it will select all the columns from the table giving performance issues. The account table has indexes with non key columns included in the index to perform faster lookup and return of the data.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comments. "select a from Address A" queries are fine; you control what is fetched in the managed Address via an entityGraph, which makes everything not defined in it lazily fetched and not included in the select statement. Try it! You just might need to define more in there than 'app', as you'll need the ID at the least. Indexing is a separate concern and issue; you do not need to limit what you fetch because of indexes, they should only affect what you use in the where clauses, which you can add to any query.

Comment: On the table there is index like CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_index ON gateway_account(app_id, account_number) INCLUDE(bank_name, account_holder_name);.
This is done because in the select query the columns in INCLUDE will be there in select clause and not in where clause. When this query is executed MSSQL will not go to the main table to get the non key columns after finding the reference in the index.

 select a from Address A will always go to main table as it selects all the column that are not there in the index(key and non key columns).

Comment: Still I'm not following your concern. EntityGraphs are there to limit what is fetched - thereby limiting what is included in the select clause. You should be able to limit it using the entity graph to only the fields in your index. It should NOT go to the main table if you've added in the where clause to filter on your indexed properties. I thought it was clear you still had to add the where clause and specify your EntityGraph. So does it work? Show the SQL generated and what you are really after if it isn't this - are you just trying to select 'Account_.APP'?